# join table between 2 persistance unit

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two different persistence units in my application. I'm using JPA 2.0 as ejb3.0 as my entity provider. In one of my database schemas, I have a table which contains a column which has a foreign key relationship to a table in the other schema. These tables are mapped as separate entities in my code with no relationship. Is it possible to construct a named query to join across these two schemas?

Answer (score 0):

across 2 schemas, yes. 
across 2 persistence units no, since anything referenced has to be present in the persistence unit. 
No reason why a persistence unit can't have entities from 2 schemas

Comment: my task is to create a distributed database from a single database to increase the speed of overall system. so the single database is now maintained in 2 diffrent pc. so now i want to connect those through jpa witout lossing any value.                                                               i was susccesful when there is no relationship b/w tables but not able to manage when there is connection                              Plesae help me with this problem

Comment: I answered the question asked; you don't then go and change the question. Suggest you read the FAQ for this site and target any future questions raised